# knockout.js --> what is it? --> $.map

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
 self.save = function() {
        var dataToSave = $.map(self.lines(), function(line) {
            return line.product() ? {
                productName: line.product().name,
                quantity: line.quantity(),
                price: line.product().price
            } : undefined
        });
        alert("Could now send this to server: " + JSON.stringify(dataToSave));
    }; 
 };
```

This is an example  tha you can find in official site of  knockout.js
i need a simil configuration for my spare.
I have to make sure that I read data from my database, how can I do?

Comment: See docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) of $.map you can read.

> Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.

$.map is equivalent to [ko.utils.arrayMap](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html).

> ko.utils.arrayMap executes a function for each item in an array and
>   pushes the result of the function to a new array that is returned.

Comment: aaaaahhhh now i'm understanding

Comment: One small difference: jQuery's `map` passes the index of each item as the second argument of the mapping function, whereas Knockout's implementation doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

$ is an alias for jQuery.
please check the official documentation of jQuery.map() for further information:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Comment: thanks sorry for the ignorance